# How to read a csv file and create a new csv file after every nth number of rows?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a function that reads a sheet of an existing .csv file and every 20 rows are copied to a newly created csv file. Therefore, it needs to be designed like a file counter "file_01, file_02, file_04,...," where the first 20 rows are copied to file_01, the next 20 to file_02.csv, and so on.

Currently I have this code which hasn't worked for me work so far.

```
import csv
import os.path
from itertools import islice

N = 20
new_filename = ""
filename = ""
with open(filename, "rb") as file:  # the a opens it in append mode
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i in range(N):
        line = next(file).strip()
        #print(line)
with open(new_filename, 'wb') as outfh:
            writer = csv.writer(outfh)
            writer.writerow(line)
            writer.writerows(islice(reader, 2))
```

I have attached a file for testing.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhdJmaLEPcR8htYqFooEoYUwDzdZbg

```
32.01,18.42,58.98,33.02,55.37,63.25,12.82,-32.42,33.99,179.53,
41.11,33.94,67.85,57.61,59.23,94.69,19.43,-19.15,21.71,-161.13,
49.80,54.12,72.78,100.74,56.97,128.84,26.95,-6.76,10.07,-142.62,
55.49,81.02,68.93,148.17,49.25,157.32,34.94,5.39,0.44,-123.32,
56.01,112.81,59.27,177.87,38.50,179.63,43.43,18.42,-5.81,-102.24,
50.79,142.87,48.06,-162.32,26.60,-161.21,52.38,34.37,-7.42,-79.64,
41.54,167.36,37.12,-145.93,15.01,-142.84,60.90,57.05,-4.47,-56.54,
30.28,-172.09,27.36,-130.24,5.11,-123.66,66.24,91.12,-0.76,-35.44,
18.64,-153.20,19.52,-114.09,-1.54,-102.96,64.77,131.32,5.12,-21.68,
7.92,-134.07,14.24,-96.93,-3.79,-80.91,57.10,162.35,12.51,-9.21,
-0.34,-113.74,11.80,-78.73,-2.49,-58.46,46.75,-175.86,20.81,2.87,
-4.81,-91.85,11.78,-60.28,0.59,-39.26,35.75,-158.12,29.79,15.71,
-4.76,-68.67,13.79,-43.84,6.82,-24.69,25.27,-141.56,39.05,30.71,
-1.33,-46.42,18.44,-30.23,14.53,-11.95,16.21,-124.45,47.91,50.25,
4.14,-29.61,24.89,-18.02,23.01,0.10,9.59,-106.05,54.46,77.07,
11.04,-15.39,32.33,-6.66,31.92,12.48,6.24,-86.34,55.72,110.53,
18.69,-2.32,40.46,4.57,41.11,26.87,6.07,-65.68,50.25,142.78,
26.94,10.56,49.18,16.67,49.92,45.39,8.06,-46.86,40.13,168.29,
35.80,24.58,58.45,31.99,56.83,70.92,12.96,-31.90,28.10,-171.07,

44.90,41.72,67.41,55.89,59.21,103.94,19.63,-18.67,15.97,-152.40,
-5.41,-77.62,11.40,-63.21,4.80,-29.06,31.33,-151.44,43.00,37.25,
-2.88,-54.38,13.08,-46.00,12.16,-15.86,21.21,-134.62,51.25,59.16,
1.69,-35.73,17.44,-32.01,20.37,-3.78,13.06,-117.10,56.18,88.98,
8.15,-20.80,23.70,-19.66,29.11,8.29,7.74,-98.22,54.91,123.30,
15.52,-7.45,31.04,-8.22,38.22,21.78,5.76,-77.99,47.34,153.31,
23.53,5.38,39.07,2.98,47.29,38.71,6.58,-57.45,36.18,176.74,
32.16,18.76,47.71,14.88,55.08,61.71,9.76,-40.52,23.99,-163.75,
41.27,34.36,56.93,29.53,59.23,92.75,15.53,-26.40,12.16,-145.27,
49.92,54.65,66.04,51.59,57.34,126.97,22.59,-13.65,2.14,-126.20,
55.50,81.56,72.21,90.19,49.88,155.84,30.32,-1.48,-4.71,-105.49,
55.92,113.45,70.26,139.40,39.23,178.48,38.55,10.92,-7.09,-83.11,
50.58,143.40,61.40,172.50,27.38,-162.27,47.25,24.86,-4.77,-60.15,
41.30,167.74,50.34,-166.33,15.74,-143.93,56.21,43.14,-0.54,-38.22,
30.03,-171.78,39.24,-149.48,5.71,-124.87,63.77,70.19,4.75,-24.15,
18.40,-152.91,29.17,-133.78,-1.18,-104.31,66.51,108.81,11.86,-11.51,
7.69,-133.71,20.84,-117.74,-3.72,-82.28,61.95,146.15,20.05,0.65,
-0.52,-113.33,14.97,-100.79,-2.58,-59.75,52.78,172.46,28.91,13.29,
-4.91,-91.36,11.92,-82.84,0.34,-40.12,41.93,-167.91,38.21,27.90,
```

Comment: You are at the internet search engine step of the development process. If you have problems while you implement the solution feel free to stop back here and post code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Some code that you have written that isn't working correctly yet, or more fine grained questions about how to do the solution would be helpful.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a design or coding resource.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Can you kindly open it again. I haven't been able to solve it as of yet.

Comment: I've edited 2 sets of 20 lines from the CSV file *into* the post itself. Next time, make sure to provide [mcve] of your problem, which includes posting sample inputs *into* the post itself, not in some external link. External links can change over time (ex. you might delete that file) and it won't be available anymore for other readers who might have the same problem or future visitors of your post.

Comment: Your test CSV file has a blank line at the start. Is that intentional?

Comment: @GinoMempin not the first one was by accident

Comment: Your test file is a bit confusing, because you have CSV format but it is saved in an Excel file. Is that your actual test input? Is the input really an Excel file? Because it won't work with reading it line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some of the problems with your current solution.

1. You created a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object but then you did not use it
2. You read each line but then you did not store them anywhere
3. You are not keeping track of 20 rows which was supposed to be your requirement
4. You created the output file in a separate `with` block which does not have access anymore to the read lines or the `csv.reader` object

Here's a working solution:

```
import csv

inp_file = "input.csv"
out_file_pattern = "file_{:{fill}2}.csv"
max_rows = 20

with open(inp_file, "r") as inp_f:
    reader = csv.reader(inp_f)

    all_rows = []
    cur_file = 1

    for row in reader:
        all_rows.append(row)

        if len(all_rows) == max_rows:
            with open(out_file_pattern.format(cur_file, fill="0"), "w") as out_f:
                writer = csv.writer(out_f)
                writer.writerows(all_rows)
            all_rows = []
            cur_file += 1
```

The flow is as follows:

1. Read each row of the CSV using a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)
2. Store each row in an `all_rows` list
3. Once that list gets 20 rows, open a file and write all the rows to it

   - Use the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)'s [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method
   - Use a `cur_file` counter to format the filename
4. Every time 20 rows are dumped to a file, empty out the list and increment the file counter

This solution includes the blank lines as part of the 20 rows. Your [test file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhdJmaLEPcR8htYqFooEoYUwDzdZbg) has actually 19 rows of CSV data and 1 row for a blank line. If you need to skip the blank line, just add a simple check of

```
if not row: 
    continue
```

Also, as I mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263726/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-create-a-new-csv-file-after-every-nth-number-of-rows#comment108443450_61263726), I assume that the input file is an *actual* CSV file, meaning it's a plain text file with CSV formatted data. If the input is actually an Excel file, then solutions like this won't work, because you'll need some special libraries to read Excel files, even if the contents *visually* looks like CSV or even if you rename the file to `.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any special CSV libraries (e.g. `csv`, though you could, just that I don't know how to use them, however don't think it is necessary for this case), you could:

```py
excel_csv_fp = open(r"<file_name>", "r", encoding="utf-8") # Check proper encoding for your file
csv_data = excel_csv_fp.readlines()
file_counter = 0
new_file_name = ""
new_fp = ""
for line in csv_data:
    if line == "":
        if new_fp != "":
            new_fp.close()
        file_counter += 1
        new_file_name = "file_" + "{:02d}".format(file_counter) # 1 turns into 01 and 10 turns 10 i.e. remains the same
        new_fp = open("<some_path>/" + new_file_name + ".csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") # Makes a new CSV file to start writing to
    elif new_fp != "": # Updated code to make sure new_fp is a file pointer and not a string
        new_fp.write(line) # Write each line after a space
```

If you have any questions on any of the code (how it works, why I choose what etc.), just ask in the comments and I'll try to reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and I get this error for some reason 

```
    new_fp.write(line) # Write each line after a space
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: @ShayanRiyaz Hi, okay. I updated the code. Also don't forget to mark this as the correct answer and upvote if it answers your problems, thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution. The code runs but it is not giving me any output.

Comment: @ShayanRiyaz So it doesn't create any new files?

Comment: yes, there is no output. The code runs and without any errors but it does not create any files

Comment: Yes, there is no output to the console. It is meant to create files that you specified in your question.

Comment: Put the exact code in your question. Also, I see that you changed the CSV file without having blank lines. The code won't work if you don't have the blank line after every 20 lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211900/discussion-between-shayan-riyaz-and-user12055579).